# Debugging assembly load issue in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I created two projects. They are VB.Net dll and c# .net dll file. I am using VB.net dll file into c#.dll file. when i test c#.net dll file it is giving error message **Could not load assemble**. if i use both then it is working fine.But i have to use only one dll file. 
Let me know how can i do with only c#.net dll file.

Comment: you should implement everything in the single C# dll, or you need to use the both of them

Comment: yes ! i have to implement everything in c# dll file.

Comment: This is not the purpose of Assembly.Load. If you want to merge two projects you'll have to look at other options. I suggest you put all your code into one project and stick to one language. Otherwise, ILMerge might do what you need.

Answer (score 3):

In .NET a project denotes the bounds of the resulting assembly. So if you want a single .dll you will need to put everything in a single project.

You have the additional task in your case of making everything the same language as you can't mix VB.NET and C#.NET in a single project.